# gedit-dash not working anymore

Tags: gedit, plugins

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/gedit-dash-new-tab-gedit-plugin-powered.html) on getting Gedit dash installed but for some reason it doesn't work anymore. I wrote a silent script that does everything automatically:

```
cd /tmp
sudo apt-get -y install python-pygments
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7162902/gedit-dash.tar.gz
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
sudo file-roller gedit-dash.tar.gz --extract-to=/home/username/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

and gedit-dash worked fine. But then it just stop working. When i go to the plugins menu, I select the `Dashboard`, no errors, but i still don't get gedit-dash?

<sup>**Note**: zeitgeist and zeitgeist-extensions-fts are also installed</sup>

Answer (score 1):

gedit. is a powerful text-editor that can be extended with some plugins one of my favorite plugin is gedit-dash although you can't install it via ubuntu-software-center but you can download the files from a Dropbox url the quickest way to install is via command line like this.

## dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pygments
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7162902/gedit-dash.tar.gz
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
sudo file-roller gedit-dash.tar.gz --extract-to=/home/YOUR USERNAME/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

rename the "YOUR USERNAME" comment to... your username

while we are taking about installing gedit-dash lets upgrade to the latest stable version of gedit [(3.2.6)](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.2/gedit-3.2.6.tar.xz) this may take 10 min or less.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gedit

cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.2/gedit-3.2.6.tar.xz
tar Jxf gedit-3.2.6.tar.xz
cd gedit-3.2.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

hope this will help